# android: The Local Service is running in the UI thread,the same as Activity?

Tags: android, service

I know the local service runs in the UI thread of the main process, the same as activity.
According to this principle，it shouldn't work immediately when I do something in an activity, if something time-consuming is running in service.

But the example below isn't so.
Who can tell me the truth?
Much appreciate!

```
package com.example.testservice;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "LocalService";
private MyService.LocalBinder binder = new MyService.LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            //I do something time-consuming in here.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Name:" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + ".Service i:" + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onUnbind!");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

}
```

Below is the Activity code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.btnTimeConsuming:
        for(int i = 1;i <= 10; i ++)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Name:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ".Activity i:" + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btnStartService:
        startService(intent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

When I click the Button "R.id.btnStartService",the I click the Button "R.id.btnTimeConsuming"
It print the below Log.
[image]

The task in Service and the task in Service is complicating. Why?

Comment: How is your service declared in manifest?

Comment: It's my fault.The service declared is "android:process=".remote".I know the reason.Thank you.